# SOQL Query to get all partners of an opportunity

Tags: apex, soql, query

Need help retrieving all the partners from an opportunity given its id.
This is what I thought it be :

```
List<Opportunity> temp = [Select (Select Role from OpportunityPartners)
From Opportunity where id='12345567'];
```

Not working though...and not sure what's wrong either

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error?

Comment: Just saying the syntax is incorrect

Comment: Hmm, try adding at least one field to the outer query - say Id - [Select Id, (Select Role from OpportunityPartners)
From Opportunity where id='12345567']

Comment: @user2582622 If any of the below answers [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a script you may find useful to run through `Execute Anonymous`:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Opportunity.getChildRelationships())
{
    String name = relation.getRelationshipName();
    if (name != null && name.contains('Partner'))
        system.debug(name + ' (' + relation.getChildSObject() + ')');
}
```

This script yields three relationships:

> AccountPartners (AccountPartner)
>   OpportunityPartnersFrom (OpportunityPartner)
>   Partners (Partner)

It seems to me you want door #2, which would make your query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Role FROM OpportunityPartnersFrom) FROM Opportunity
```

Comment: Although since you added in a nice script, +1

Answer (score 4):

Change your query to:

```
List<Opportunity> temp = [Select (Select Role from OpportunityPartnersFrom)
From Opportunity where id='12345567'];
```

From the Opportunity context that's it's API Name

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need any fields from the Opportunity then you can query the OpportunityPartners object directly:

```
List< OpportunityPartner > temp = [Select Role from OpportunityPartner
Where OpportunityID ='12345567'];
```

Otherwise you will need to use the correct API Name of the relationship

```
List<Opportunity> temp = [Select (Select Role from OpportunityPartnersFrom)
From Opportunity where id='12345567'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `sObject` in your first query be `OpportunityPartner`, not `OpportunityPartners`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - yup was still in edit of the answer then everyone showed up lol. Glad we have this problem......

Comment: Fastest fingers in the west! Yay participation.

Comment: @AdrianLarson (And Eric) Definitely a dead heat on this one! (I like the alternative solution too)

Comment: How would I add an `Opportunity Partner` object to a specific opportunity? Assuming I have the id of the opportunity

Comment: I understand this is old thread, but please know that the SOQL will also pull the Account that is tied to the Opportunity. You may want to add additional WHERE clause, something like this - "WHERE AccountToId != Opportunity.AccountId"